# Restrict Parallel Logging in Spring Security Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am using `HttpSecurity`
Here I want to Restrict Parallel Logging.
i.e if user_A is logged in then user_A should not be able to logging at the same time. and at the same time user_B can logging but user_A should not.

Here is my code

```
 @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    //Disable CSRF protection
    http
          .invalidateHttpSession(true)
          .and()
          .exceptionHandling()
          .authenticationEntryPoint(new Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint())
          .and()
          .csrf()//Disable CSRF protection
          .disable()
          .sessionManagement()
          .maximumSessions(1)
          .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true);
}
```

here I am using `SessionManagement` with `MaximumSession(1)`
but the problem is when user_A logged in, user_A is able to logged in successfully but when user_A logged out user_A is not able to logging again.
so please help to restrict parallel user logging.

Comment: The he isn't logged out.

Comment: Have you defined `HttpSessionEventPublisher` as a bean?

Comment: @sura2k no but can it will run on defining it ? and above `sessionManagement` i used is proper ?

Comment: If not, try with @Bean `HttpSessionEventPublisher`

Comment: @sura2k can you share your answer because I am not getting how to use `HttpSessionEventPublisher` and `SessionRegistry`

Comment: here i change my spring security version ie. 4.1.0 RELEASE. so now it is working